# Weierstrass equation help needed

Tags: weierstrass-factorization

thanks in advance.

I am trying to prove that the Weierstrass equation
y^2+a1xy+a3y=x^3+a2x^2+a4x+a6 can be written in the form of:
y2=x3+ax+b ,curves are over some field K where char K≠2,3.

I found out that this could be done by completing the square and a substitution that will eliminates some coefficients.
But couldn't find any step by step explanation. and I tried to do it for hours, but not succeeded. 
If I do just the RHS  (x^3+a2x^2+a4x+a6) and substitue x->x-a/3 then the coefficient of x^2 becomes 0, and I keep try to manipulate the LHS (y^2+a1xy+a3y) , no idea what to do now
Can anyone please help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Write the left as $y^2+(a_1x+a_3)y$ then complete the square

$$y^2+(a_1x+a_3)y=\left(y+\frac{1}{2}(a_1x+a_3)\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_1x+a_3)\right)^2$$

So you
have
$$\left(y+\frac{1}{2}(a_1x+a_3)\right)^2=x^3+
a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6+ 
\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_1x+a_3)\right)^2$$

Now use the trick you described on the RHS.